# Metro bundler is not shown up after : npx react-native run-android

Tags: react-native

when I run my project I cannot see the bundler running, it just loads and builds successfully but then disconnects. what is the problem?

Comment: You can start the bundler with `npx react-native start`.

Comment: It didn't work as well. I tried both cmd and Git bash, nothing different. I tried many suggestions I found in my google search, but nothing worked !!

Comment: Explain exactly what you're doing and what is going wrong

Comment: after downloading Android studio, etc, I created a react-native project folder and run react-native init myProject. then, I run react-native-start. The terminal shows up, but no QR code shows up, also, when I run react-native run-android, it builds successfully but without a metro bundle terminal.

Comment: A QR code shows up if you're using expo, not react-native cli. `npx react-native start` and `npx react-native run-android` should also be run in separate terminal instances.

Comment: I found this solution in a GitHub issue, it worked for me:

Replace the code with this one. The path of the file is:
node_modules\metro-config\src\defaults\blacklist.js

var sharedBlacklist = [
  /node_modules[\/\\]react[\/\\]dist[\/\\].*/,
  /website\/node_modules\/.*/,
  /heapCapture\/bundle\.js/,
  /.*\/__tests__\/.*/
];

Also, I wasn't keeping both terminals open together, so THANk YOU, @BasvanderLinden :)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend these steps:

1. make sure you have a compatible version of SDK build-tools, try to keep only one. (Also, SDK 11 might be better than SDK 14), Gradle version might have to be downgraded to 6.3, and start with Marshmellow (API 23), (that is what React Native page recommends).
2. Try this option if you cannot connect to the development server:
   create assets folder if you cannot find it in:

   ```
    cd android/app/src/main/assets
   ```

   then cd to project folder and run:

   ```
    react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res
   ```
3. some people say that react-native-cli might cause some issues, so try uninstalling it.